# Debian - Execute a python script with modules import

Tags: debian, cron, python

In `Debian 10 (buster)` I wan't to schedule a task with `cron`. This task is a `python` script who create a `csv` file. This `python` script start with:

```
import xmlrpc.client
import csv
```

When I execute it, without any `cron` task, I have this message:

```
/usr/bin/python /home/debian/api_odoo_contact.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/debian/api_odoo_contact.py", line 1, in <module>
    import xmlrpc.client
ImportError: No module named xmlrpc.client
```

How to resolve this modules dependencies ?

Do I have to install modules on my server before excuting the script and define their paths in my `python` script ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xmlrpc.client` is a Python 3 library (it was `xmlrpclib` in Python 2), so you need to specify a Python 3 interpreter:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/debian/api_odoo_contact.py
```

In Debian 10, `/usr/bin/python` is a Python 2 interpreter.